# axios delete function not working

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

I am trying to create a delete button, on my surveys i have the delete button and my end api created however nothing happens when i  hit delete on the survey please help.

This is where my delete button and function is.
 created a new function called `newDelete` and passed it the survey._id but that is not working either

SurveyList.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchSurveys } from '../../actions';
import { deleteSurvey } from '../../actions';

class SurveyList extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchSurveys();
  }

  newDelete() {
  deleteSurvey('{survey._id}');
  }

  renderSurveys() {
    return this.props.surveys.reverse().map(survey => {
      return (
        <div className="card darken-1" key={survey._id}>
          <div className="card-content">
            <span className="card-title">{survey.title}</span>
            <p>
              {survey.body}
            </p>
            <p className="right">
            <button type="button" onClick={this.newDelete}>DELETE</button>
              Sent On: {new Date(survey.dateSent).toLocaleDateString()}
            </p>
          </div>

        </div>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderSurveys()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ surveys }) {
  return { surveys };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchSurveys })(SurveyList);
```

where i have my api's.

```
index.js 

import axios from "axios";
import { FETCH_USER, FETCH_SURVEYS } from "./types";


export const fetchUser = () => async dispatch => {
  const res = await axios.get("/api/current_user");

  dispatch({ type: FETCH_USER, payload: res.data });
};

export const submitSurvey = (values, history) => async dispatch => {
  const res = await axios.post("/api/surveys", values);

  history.push("/surveys");
  dispatch({ type: FETCH_USER, payload: res.data });
};

export const fetchSurveys = () => async dispatch => {
  const res = await axios.get('/api/surveys');

    dispatch({type: FETCH_SURVEYS, payload: res.data })
};

export const deleteSurvey = (values, history) => async dispatch => {
  const res = await axios.delete('api/surveys', {params: {'_id': values}});

  history.push("/surveys");
  dispatch({ type: FETCH_USER, payload: res.data });
};
```

this is the part of the code where i am trying to just delete the surveys.  any help will be greatly appreciated thanks.nothing happens no errors nor any console issues.

Comment: Hey see the url passed to axios.delete(), currently you are passing `api/surveys`. Change it to `/api/surveys` and see if it fixes.

Comment: thanks i fixed that still have the same error man

Comment: Hey can you share you back-end code as well. Thanks.

Comment: app.delete('/api/surveys/:surveyId', function (req,res) {
    res.send("Deleted");
  });
Thats my backend  thanks a bunch

Comment: I guess the route expected in the back-end does not match the route being used in front-end. In back-end you are expecting `:surveyId` where in front-end you are passing it as `params`. Your url should be `api/surveys/lsdjfdsafldflfl_random_id` in  fact it is `/api/surveys?_id=value`

Try changing url in

  const res = await axios.delete('api/surveys/' + values}});